# Adding PXFilterable to grid gives an error rendering page design mode

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen (FormDetail) with a grid to which I've added the filter component in the grid's header section.  When I add the [PXFilterable] attribute to the detail view in the BLC, The page shows fine in a browser, but the design mode of the page displays the following errors:

[image]

The view with the attributes is as follows (included above it is the header section view);

```
    public PXSelect<xTACTodoHeader> TodoHeader;

    [PXImport(typeof(xTACTodoHeader))]
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXSelect<xTACTodoDetail,
           Where<xTACTodoDetail.entityType, Equal<Current<xTACTodoHeader.entityType>>,
           And<xTACTodoDetail.dataID, Equal<Current<xTACTodoHeader.dataID>>>>> TodoDetail;
```

Am I missing something?  Like I said, the form displays fine, but I don't like seeing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With previous builds there was an issue inside the framework, that should be addressed in very latest 5.3 and 6.x builds. Could you please upgrade to the latest released build to check if the issue gets resolved after that?

Comment: Will do.  Thanks, Ruslan.